# do not collapse empty nodes in XML output

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I'm using python's `xml.etree.ElementTree` to represent an XML document. I want to output it to text but I want to keep empty elements (elements with no children) expanded, instead of collapsed. E.g., I want this:

```
<element></element>
```

Instead of this:

```
<element />
```

I'm currently using `ElementTree.tostring`, but I'm willing to use any other built-in python modules or functions to serialize the document, as long as I can pretty easily use an ElementTree object with it.

FYI, the reason I want to keep the elements expanded is because I want to more easily diff the output with output from a third party program which doesn't collapse empty elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass `method="html"` to the [`tostring()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) call.

Demo:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
>>> data = """
... <root>
...     <person/>
...     <person></person>
... </root>
... """
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(data)
>>> print etree.tostring(tree, method="html")
<root>
    <person></person>
    <person></person>
</root>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, html output method does not properly preserve the case of tags. For instance, if you have a mixed case tag like "peasantFarmer", the opening tag is correct, but the closing tag is "peasantfarmer" (notice lower-case 'f'). Not sure if this is a bug or if its deliberate because HTML is supposed to be case insensitive (though I would have thought tag pairs still need to match).

Comment: This removes the XML declaration, even if you use `xml_declaration=True`.

Answer (score 5):

Just use: `ElementTree.tostring(element, short_empty_elements=False)`

Comment: That also works when saving the whole document to a file
tree.write(file_name, encoding="UTF-8", short_empty_elements=False)