# Force ElementTree to use closing tag

Tags: python, xml, string, python-2.7, elementtree

Instead of having:

```
<child name="George"/>
```

at the XML file, I need to have:

```
<child name="George"></child>
```

An ugly workaround is to write a whitespace as text (not an empty string, as it will ignore it):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ch = ET.SubElement(parent, 'child')
ch.set('name', 'George')
ch.text = ' '
```

Then, since I am using Python 2.7, I read [Python etree control empty tag format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460677/python-etree-control-empty-tag-format), and tried the html method, like so:

```
ch = ET.tostring(ET.fromstring(ch), method='html')
```

but this gave:

```
TypeError: Parse() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not Element
```

and I am not sure what what I should do to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: "*at the XML file, I need to have: `<child name="George"></child>`"* you really don't, unless you are doing something to the XML that you are not supposed to be doing (like using regex to parse it later).

Comment: @Tomalak the "other guy" needs it that way.

Comment: And what are they doing, exactly, that justifies this requirement?

Comment: They are parsing that XML file in a way that requires this structure @Tomalak. Changing that old parser is out of question.

Comment: So they are "parsing" the XML with something other than an XML parser. I wonder why it is that such issues always seem to be fixed at the wrong end. Oh well. :-/

Comment: @Tomalak that's a classic, isn't it? I don't really know the mechanism they use to be honest, but they asked for that structure, and I have to comply.

Comment: Hm... Look at the source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L1118 - the `tostring()` method supports a `short_empty_elements` parameter that should do what you want.

Comment: Isn't that for Python 3 @Tomalak? If not, I would be happy to see an answer.

Comment: Not sure, I was just poking around. However, nothing prevents you from monkey-patching the ET package to backport that functionality (in fact, since you *always* want to be it that way, and not a switch, the monkey patch should be pretty straight-forward).

Comment: With lxml, `ch.text = ''` (empty string) works. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47817478/407651.

Comment: @mzjn lxml is something we decided to not be used, since it doesn't come built-in with Python 2.7, like `xml` does.

Comment: @mzjn lxml is something we decided to not be used, since it doesn't come built-in with Python 2.7, like `xml` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do it like this it should work fine in 2.7:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring

parent = Element('parent')
ch = SubElement(parent, 'child')
ch.set('name', 'George')

print tostring(parent, method='html')
#<parent><child name="George"></child></parent>

print tostring(child, method='html')
#<child name="George"></child>
```

Comment: Thanks all... "Short_Empty_Elements = False" worked for me ...

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone comes to this wondering about other Python versions, as discussed, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475104/do-not-collapse-empty-nodes-in-xml-output/33321568#33321568), you can use the `short_empty_elements` argument.

e.g.

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> ET.tostring(ET.Element("mytag"), encoding='unicode', short_empty_elements=False)
'<mytag></mytag>'
```

(I believe this works in Python version 3.6 onwards)

Comment: `short_empty_elements` was added in Python 3.4: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#xml-etree